# Adobe flash on Linux 64bit: "Movie not loaded" and maximum stack-size

Tags: adobe-flash, ulimit, stack

I was experiencing problems with all flash content (tried Firefox/Chromium/Opera, Ubuntu/Fedora and several Flash releases to no avail). While trying to playback any flash-movie, no video/sound playback occurred, and right-click only produced a "Movie not loaded" warning.

I accidentally narrowed-down the problem to a user-specific tweak I made in my '/etc/security/limits.conf':

```
    my_user_name         soft    stack           number_of_kbytes
```

The interesting part is that, whenever

```
    number_of_kbytes > 2097151 = 2^21,
```

this problem occurs, otherwise things are fine flash-wise.

Does anyone know why this may happen and where does this "magic number" come from? Also, is there a way to increase stack-size limits per-program (I have a C++ program which needs this sometimes).

Comment: Interesting. Is it posible to strace your browser with the large stack? Also, what happens if stack is set to "unlimited"?